# Text content disappears in div as scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to expand a child element to the very top of its parent with the following code. However, the text disappears after a while of scrolling downward in the child element. How do I fix this?

```js
function setHeight() {
  var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var panelHeight = container.offsetHeight;
  var y = panel.scrollTop;

  // YOU MUST SET THE PERCENTAGE, OR A MAX HEIGHT
  maxHeight = panelHeight * 0.9;

  var targetHeight = Math.min(maxHeight, 0.7 * panelHeight + y);
  panel.style.height = targetHeight + "px";

  document.getElementById("panelContent").style.marginTop = Math.min(y, panelHeight - maxHeight) + "px";
}

document.getElementById('panel').addEventListener("scroll", setHeight);
```

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

#panel {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Scroll up to here
  <div id="panel">
    <div id="panelContent">
      As user scroll downs here in this div, expand this div to the top but only as much as the user has scrolled down: asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasda<br>sdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasda<br>sdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasda<br>sdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd<br>sdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasda<br>sdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdasdasdasdasdasd
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ekpx3sd/

Comment: Welcome to SO! As far as i under stand you need that green section to cover header red section on scroll IF yes for that you need to remove both `position fixed` and add `height:100vh` with `overflow:scroll`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remove position fixed because the codebase I will be integrating this into does not allow it.

Comment: Then change it to `relative`